# Tiny space between image and its container

Tags: html, css

The image fills its container but it has a small red gap around it. Please see a sample code or image below. I would like the image to fill the container without the tiny space. Can it be fixed or is it related to the browser's rendering? Thanks.

[image: 1]

```css
div {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 64px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.postavy.cz/foto/doge-foto.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Everything looks good on my PC. What tiny space?

Comment: Maybe because img is an inline element?

Comment: Display: block doesn't seem to fix the problem. The red space is visible on the image in my question. I am using a 4k monitor and Chrome 93.

Comment: Instead of bg-color, why not use bg-image `background: red url(https://www.postavy.cz/foto/doge-foto.jpg) center / cover;`?

Comment: Please see my comment under @Lalalena post.

Comment: Could be a glitch in Chrome. Because if I inspect the element and uncheck/check some properties the red _halo_ around the image goes away. I am guessing there is not much you can do about it.

Comment: If your image takes the whole div, I don't see the need for the background colour so your reasoning for having it in a div with a background colour makes no sense unless you need the background colour if the image tag is not present (in which case you should just use your server side code to add a class if there is no image present)

Comment: @Pete what if the image is a transparent icon? Then yes, I need a background color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Chromium on Linux i can see the tiny red space.
I assume it's a clipping error.
Any way to include the image as background-image of the div? The unwanted space disappears on my browser this way.

```css
div {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 64px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(https://www.postavy.cz/foto/doge-foto.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
}
```

But, why have the red background of the div anyways if the image fills it out?

Comment: Glad you can reproduce the issue. Due to the context of how the code block will be used, I need the img tag inside a div with background color. Rather than a different approach, I would like to know why this happens and if it can be fixed.

Comment: Funny thing i noticed! If i disable any clipping related property in Chrome Web Tools and enable it again, the clipping error disappears.

Have you tried clip path instead of border-radius yet.
`clip-path: circle(50% at center);`